# How extract a snapshot from a Time Machine backup to a new external HD partion so that this partion can act as a (boot) volume?

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, external-disk, restore

I found out [how to extract a snapshot from a Time Machine backup to an external hard drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433735/how-extract-a-time-machine-snapshot-as-a-full-machine-volume/434562#434562). I use:

```
sudo tmutil restore /Volumes/TMdrive/Backups.backupdb/machinename/2021-11-30-042315/MyHD /Volumes/Safety-HD
```

(where `Safety-HD` is the external HD and `TMdrive` is my Time Machine backup drive).

However after running this command (and waiting for a day or so) when I look at the resulting file system on the new external HD `Safety-HD` I notice  the files and folders from the normal machine root (like `Application`, `Library` or `System`) are *inside*  a folder `MyHD`:

```
MyHD --+
       |
       +- Applications
       |
       +- Library
       |
       +- Network
       |
       +- System
       |
       +- Users
       |
       +- ...
```

It is obvious that I never be able to make a bootable drive out of this! - *How can I tell `tmutil` to restore *to the root* of the external drive?*

**Note 1:** I tried the `-v` option like in `sudo tmutil restore -v ...`, but I get the same resulting  folder structure  (plus a *very* long list of info in the Terminal).

**Note 2:** I know I can restore to the internal harddrive via Recovery HD, but firstly this doesn't work for external drives, plus it is pretty cumbersome to reboot the whole system when I just want to create a safety bootable drive from an old TM snapshot.

Comment: Can‘t you just `mv /Volumes/MyHD/MyHD/* /Volumes/MyHD/`? It won‘t make the drive bootable, but then you can‘t boot from TM anyway?

Comment: @nohillside That’s an idea, but I’m worried that some (soft?) links in the copied FS might be set wrongly then. Furthermore, via the Recovery Hd you *can* create bootable extracts of TM,so i was hoping there is a way to do so with Apple’s `tmutil` as well…